# R match.call() for S4 methods

Tags: r

I am currently  writing a method for an S4 class and I would like to get the call to the method as if it was a function and using match.call().

Here my minimal example of what I am doing:

```
setClass(
  Class = "AClass",
  representation = representation(
    name = "character"
  )
)

setGeneric("meth1", function(object, ...) {
  standardGeneric("meth1")
})

setMethod(
  f = "meth1",
  signature = "AClass",
  definition = function(object, method, ..., warnings = TRUE) {
    # ...
    print(match.call())

    return(NA)
})
```

With this definition I see:

```
> meth1(new("AClass"), method = "MClust")
.local(object = object, method = "MClust")
[1] NA
> meth1(new("AClass"), method = Mclust)
.local(object = object, method = ..1)
[1] NA
```

The questions are:

1. Why when assigning a function to the argument 'method' the content got from `match.call()` for this argument is `..1` insetad fo `"Mclust"`?
2. Why the 'function's name' got from `match.call()` is `.local` instead of `meth1`?
3. How can I get `"Mclust"` from the variable `method` being in the function?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by question 3?  Do you want to interpret the `MClust` symbol as a character?  In other words, you want to allow your users to type in a `MClust` without having to quote it?

Comment: In fact, you answered all the questions. What I want is to get the string `"MClust"` assigned to `method`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with how `match.call` works when there are `...` involved and multiple layers of function calls.  This is related to `match.call` searching through the lexical stack to find the `...` to substitute, instead of the dynamic stack. I wrote a package to try to correct these issues:

```
devtools::install_github("brodieg/matchcall")  # <-- the package in question
library(matchcall)
setMethod(
  f = "meth1",
  signature = "AClass",
  definition = function(object, method, ..., warnings = TRUE) {
    # ...
    print(match.call())
    print(match_call())
    print(match_call(2))
    return(NA)
  })
meth1(new("AClass"), method = Mclust)
```

Produces:

```
.local(object = object, method = ..1)               # match.call
.local(object = object, method = Mclust)            # match_call(), my package
meth1(object = new("AClass"), method = Mclust)      # match_call(2), my package offset
[1] NA
```

So, to answer question 2, the reason you get `.local` is because there is a sequence of calls that eventually lead to the evaluation of the function you have defined, and that S4 stores that function as `.local`.

The answer to question 1 is complicated, but you can look at the details in the **[vignette](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brodieG/matchcall/master/inst/doc/matchcallissues.html)** included with my package.  Note that internally in C code `...` arguments have names `..1`, `..2`, etc (**from [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Dot_002ddot_002ddot-arguments))**:

> Recall that the evaluation frame for a function initially contains the name=value pairs from the matched call, and hence this will be true for ... as well. The value of ... is a (special) pairlist whose elements are referred to by the special symbols ..1, ..2, … which have the DDVAL bit set: when one of these is encountered it is looked up (via ddfindVar) in the value of the ... symbol in the evaluation frame.

Re question 3, I don't understand it.  Do you want to be able to put in an unquoted variable as the argument "method", and then interpret that as a character?

Note the package is currently only on github, but you may be able to use `sys.calls` to meet your needs.  For example, if we run `print(sys.calls())` within your method, we get:

```
[[1]]
meth1(new("AClass"), method = Mclust)

[[2]]
meth1(new("AClass"), method = Mclust)

[[3]]
.local(object, ...)
```

You can potentially work directly with that, but this will only work well provided that you fully specify argument names in the call (i.e. if someone does `meth1(x, "blah")`, you won't get the `method=` part of it in `sys.calls`.  If you have multiple arguments or partially specified arguments (e.g. `meth=X`) then you'll have to do more work to match stuff (and that's exactly what `match_call` does).